# jQuery AJAX request gets called twice when using Jquery, Django and Google App Engine

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine, Jquery and Django. I want POST data to be sent to the server side when a form is submitted, and I do this in JQuery with the following code:

```
    $("#listform").submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/xhrtest",
                    data: {'name': 'herman'},
                    success: function(data){
                            console.log(data)
                    }
            });
    })
```

In my Django view:

```
def xhrtest(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
                return HttpResponse("Post data!")
        else:
                return HttpResponse("GET request.")
```

I would have expected to receive a reply of "Post data!", but somehow the reply is always "GET request". This is not a unicode issue either, since one can print the request.method and see "GET".

When assessing this in Firebug, I see two requests going through: First a POST request, which receives the reply "GET request." and then a GET request, which receives the reply "Get request." as well. In the Google App Engine development console I can also see two requests going through. The POST request is met with a 301 response, and the GET with 200.

What does this mean, and what do I have to do be able to receive POST data?

Comment: Is request.method (in your django code) in the correct case? If it's "post", it won't equal "POST".

Comment: Some server configuration is redirecting your POST requests, looks like. (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that you are requesting the url `/xhrtest`, without a final slash. By default, Django will redirect that request to `/xhrtest/` - with a final slash - and that redirection will be a GET, not a POST.

For more info, see the [`APPEND_SLASH`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#append-slash) setting that configures this behavior and [`CommonMiddleware`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/middleware/common.py#L55) module that uses it.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I didn't know django had that default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "turn-off" your `submit-button` at first.

```js
        $("#listform").off('submit').submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/xhrtest",
                        data: {'name': 'herman'},
                        success: function(data){
                                console.log(data)
                        }
                });
        })
```

It works with `click` too.